# Cocoapods Pod Lib Create The file ####.xcworkspace does not exist

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

I'm trying to create a cocoapod using pod lib create but for some reason the .xcworkspace file is never created.

I've tried updating Ruby and I've tried using Ruby 2.0.0 which my colleague is using and it works fine for him.

Here is the output from the pod lib create command:

```
tmep chris$ pod lib create hello
Cloning `https://github.com/CocoaPods/pod-template.git` into `hello`.
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:55: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/rvm/gems in PATH, mode 040777
Configuring hello template.
/Users/chris/tmep/hello/setup/TemplateConfigurator.rb:172: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/rvm/gems in PATH, mode 040777

------------------------------

To get you started we need to ask 4 questions, this should only take a minute.

If this is your first time we recommend running through with the guide: 
 - http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create.html
 ( hold cmd and double click links to open in a browser. )


Would you like to have a demo for your library? [ Yes / No ]
 > 
yes
Which testing frameworks will you use? [ Specta / Kiwi ]
 > 
specta
Would you like to do view based testing? [ Yes / No ]
 > 
yes
What is your class prefix?
 > OS

Running pod install on your new library.

Analyzing dependencies
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:55: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/rvm/gems in PATH, mode 040777
[!] An error occurred while performing `git pull` on repo `studio_pods`.
[!] /usr/bin/git pull --ff-only

Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'master'

from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.


 Ace! you're ready to go!
 We will start you off by opening your project in Xcode
  open 'hello/Example/hello.xcworkspace'
The file /Users/chris/tmep/hello/Example/hello.xcworkspace does not exist.

To learn more about the template see `https://github.com/CocoaPods/pod-template.git`.
To learn more about creating a new pod, see `http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod`.
```

I would be very greatful if anyone can shed any light on this issue as I'd love to get started using this great tool straightaway!

Answer (score 0):

Whoops! Just figured out what it was.

I had added a repo to pods (pod repo add) and it must have been trying to download dependancies from there!

A call to pod repo remove sorted it.